# Tesseract CLI in PHP not working, but SSH does

Tags: php, command-line-interface, tesseract

I have tesseract working with SSH, but when I use it in PHP it doesn't work. My PHP is configured to be able to execute CL.

exec('tesseract /fullpath/to/document.png /fullpath/to/output');

I use CL with IM/GS etc. and it works fine. I don't see why this fails as the command with tesseract. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Try redirecting stderr to stdout with 2>&1 to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue. I used http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ which was the quickest and easiest method for me. It took all of 30 seconds.

```
include('sshlib/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('boom command works 2>&1');
```